# Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm trying to create a chrome extension.
The objectif of the app:
open new popup window and edit the content and html
but it does not work
it show me this error in the console:

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "chrome-extension://pjnjcefdmacabhjhkkggfbcbdalfannl" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Title!",
    "description": "Description...",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/email.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Title",
        "matches": ["*://*.*/*"]
    },

    "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "storage",
    "*://*.*.*/*",
    "activeTab"
    ],

    "chrome_url_overrides": {
      "newtab" : "popup.html"
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "*://*.*/*" ],
    "js": [ "script.js" ],
    "all_frames": true
    }]

}
```

**script.js: (the error part)**

```
myWindow = window.open("https://gmail.com", "", "width=900, height=500");

myWindow.document.getElementById("elementId1").value = variable1;
myWindow.document.getElementById("elementId2").value = variable2;
```

i can't get values or change them,
i tried with a lot of urls but it shows the same error

any help please?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001541/

Comment: i don't think so,
this is not my problem, i'm not including iframe in my code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating a new window from the current content script you can provide to it meaningless for target website query string params to pass your params and also to create another content script which will have `include_globs` like 
`"https://mail.google.*/*?myparam*"`
In this new content script you can get params from query string and set them to the fields without errors.

PS: in case target website removes unknown query params you can try anchor instead.

Comment: First, thank you for your response.
In fact, I didn't understand this very well,
I tried to do this:

    myWindow = window.open("https://www.test.com/test?nick="+nick.value+"&domName="+domName, '', 'width=900,height=500');
    
    myWindow.getElementById('elementId').setAttribute('value', getParameter(1));
    
    function getParameter(a) {
        var tmp = [];
        tmp = location.search
              .substr(1)
              .split("&")
        return tmp[a].split('=')[1];
    }

but it's not working,
please explain to me.